# How do you create an event log source using WiX

Tags: wix, event-log, eventlog-source

I'm creating an installer for a website that uses a custom event log source. I would like our WiX based installer to create that event log source during installation.

Does anyone know the best way to do this using the WiX framework.

Comment: This is amazing. I was looking for exactly this solution, and thought it was too obscure to possibly already be answered here. Go figure.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Wix has out-of-the-box support for creating event log sources.

Assuming you use Wix 3, you first need to add a reference to WixUtilExtension to either your Votive project or the command line. You can then add an EventSource element under a component :

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">

    <Component ...>
        ...
        <util:EventSource Log="Application" Name="*source name*"
           EventMessageFile="*path to message file*"/>
        ...
    </Component>
```

If this is a .NET project, you can use EventLogMessages.dll in the framework directory as the message file.

Comment: [WindowsFolder]Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\EventLogMessages.dll

Comment: If you use the WixNetFxExtension, you can use [NETFRAMEWORK20INSTALLROOTDIR]EventLogMessages.dll

Comment: Just a warning for anyone trying Wim's suggestion; properties can't depend upon the result of other search properties (which `NETFRAMEWORK*` are). Just spent ages trying to figure out why a `DirectorySearch` using `NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENTINSTALLROOTDIR` wasn't working... :P

Comment: One other thing you will need to ensure is that you include -ext "%WIX_BUILD_LOCATION%\WixUtilExtension.dll" on your candle command to use any of the util: features.

Answer (score 19):

Just to save people some time - if you are trying to use the Application log and the .NET messages you can cut paste the below code:

```
<Util:EventSource
 xmlns:Util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension"
 Name="ROOT Builder"
 Log="Application"
 EventMessageFile="%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\EventLogMessages.dll"
/>
```

NOTE: the path above is now correct..

Comment: is it still v2.0.50727 or does a .NET 4 application use v4.0... ?

Comment: @gbjbaanb .Net 4.5 uses `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EventLogMessages.dll`

Comment: %SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\EventLogMessages.dll

Answer (score 18):

How about the more flexible stuff built in:

```
EventMessageFile="[NETFRAMEWORK20INSTALLROOTDIR]EventLogMessages.dll"
```

or

```
EventMessageFile="[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]EventLogMessages.dll"
```

And

```
EventMessageFile="[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR64]EventLogMessages.dll"
```

Comment: Not quite correct. In Wix 3.5 it should be [NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR] or [NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR64] (for 64bit) - see http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm.  And remember to include a PropertyRef to it.