# WIX property NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR is blank

Tags: installation, wix, setup-project

I am trying to register my COM Add-in using the RegAsm command using the WIX Setup. But am unable to do it. It is showing blank against the [WixNetFxExtension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html)'s `NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR` or even `NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENTINSTALLROOTDIR`.

Here is the code for the custom action:

```
<CustomAction Id="RegisterUsingRegAsm" Directory="PROOFIX_ADDIN" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" Return="check"
              ExeCommand='"[NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR]regasm.exe" "[PROOFIX_ADDIN]Proofix.View.dll" /codebase' />
```

When I try to hardcode the path `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe`. It works fine...

and Here is the Sequence information:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="RegisterUsingRegAsm" Before="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Here is the log generated for the installer:

> Action: RegisterUsingRegAsm, location:
>   C:\Users\naveed.butt\AppData\Local\Optimentor\Proofix\, command:
>   "regasm.exe"
>   "C:\Users\naveed.butt\AppData\Local\Optimentor\Proofix\Proofix.View.dll"
>   /codebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are missing a `PropertyRef`

Like this:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENTINSTALLROOTDIR"/>
```

Second issue if you are on a 64 bit windows you should use the 64 bit variable:

```
NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENTINSTALLROOTDIR64
```

However you can handle 32/64 bit Windows OS with conditions. You can get inspiration from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12514596/600559

Comment: I tried adding the property as well, but it didn't work. The only thing I didn't try was `64 bit` run-time, because although my OS is 64 bit but there is 32 bit run-time installed on it as well. So the question is, do I really need to change/switch to `64 bit` run-time ?

Comment: When installing (a 32 bit app) - on a 64 bit OS you need to use NETFRAMEWORK40FULLINSTALLROOTDIR64 and NETFRAMEWORK40CLIENTINSTALLROOTDIR64