# Why create event source during installation

Tags: wix, event-log

This is somewhat related to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529531/wix-and-eventlog). Basically it is trivial to write to the eventlog in .net and I am assuming other languages as well. So why would people go through the trouble of doing that in WiX? I know one reason could be permissions but is there anything else I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not write to the event log in WiX (except maybe for actually logging events that occur during installation). What you are doing in WiX is installing an Event Source for your application, which must be done with administrative privileges.

If you know the Event Source already exists, or your application will be run with Administrative privileges, you would not need to create the event source from the installer.